# Comparing file names to an array of file masks in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for the best way take a file, and test to see if it's filename contains an element in an array.

For example, the file name `AB_011_Test.txt`, and the list `@("010", "011", "012")`, I need a test to see if the file name contains one of the elements of the list. Obviously in this example it would return true, but the file `XZ_999_Test.txt` would return false.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join` all your array elements with `|` to create a pattern that can match *either* of the elements and use it along with [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) operator.

```
PS > "AB_011_Test.txt" -match (@("010", "011", "012") -Join "|")
True
PS > "XZ_999_Test.txt" -match (@("010", "011", "012") -Join "|")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that uses the intrinsic [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where) method:

```sh
$list = "010", "011", "012"

$fileName = "AB_011_Test.txt"
$list.Where({ $fileName.Contains($_) }, 'First').Count -gt 0
# -> outputs: True

$fileName = "XZ_999_Test.txt"
$list.Where({ $fileName.Contains($_) }, 'First').Count -gt 0
# -> outputs: False
```

The first argument for the `Where` method is a script block that filters the elements of the array (or other *enumerable* types), similar to the `Where-Object` command. The 2nd optional argument defines the selection mode. We pass `First` because we only need to find the first matching element to produce a `True` output.

Finally we check the `Count` member of the filtered collection to determine if there is any match.

Note that when using an `if` statement, you don't need to explicitly check the `Count` member, as non-empty collections evaluate to `$true`:

```sh
if( $list.Where({ $fileName.Contains($_) }, 'First') ) {
   Write-Host 'Match'
} else {
   Write-Host 'No match'
}
```